# Body background 100% of document width?

Tags: css

I have a body background that scales the entire width of the page.

Currently, it's set to 
background-size: 100% 50px;

The 100% works great for big screens: the background spans the width of the page as intended.
I'm looking for something that applies to smaller screens(and mobiles!) aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code to `html`

```
html { 
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: For IE you may put the filter like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";`

Answer (score 1):

I moved the background from body{} to html{}